# how can I transform the following data into pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

I have this type of data I want this each list of each id in seperate column

```
id       data
2        [1.81744912347, 1.96313966807, 1.79290908923]
3        [0.87738744314, 0.154642653196, 0.319845728764]
4        [1.12289279512, 1.16105905267, 1.14889626137]
5        [1.65093687407, 1.65010263863, 1.65614839538]
6        [0.103623262651, 0.46093367049, 0.549343505693]
7        [0.122299243819, 0.355964399805, 0.40010681636]
8        [3.08321032223, 2.92526466342, 2.6504125359, 2]
9        [0.287041436848, 0.264107869667, 0.29319302508]
10       [0.673829091668, 0.632715325748, 0.47099544284]
11       [3.04589375431, 2.19130582148, 1.68173686657]
```

how can I transform the data into the pandas DataFrame
I want it as the following data

```
id   data
1   1.61567967235
1   1.55256213176
1   1.16904355984
...
10  0.673829091668
10  0.632715325748
```

and so on

its large amount of data, if I use the loop to transform it, it kills the notebook, is there any other way to process this data,

sample image of the data
[image]

Comment: @Wen its not duplicate question, if you see the question requirements that's completely a seperate what my question is

Comment: It is still al most the same , look at my question , i convert that to list like you show in your picture , the unnesting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, from

```
col
0   [1, 2, 3]
1   [4, 5, 6]
```

can do

```
df.col.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
dtype: int64
```

or

```
pd.Series([z for x in df.col.values for z in x])

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
dtype: int64
```

Times:

```
%timeit df.col.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
1.15 ms ± 26.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series([z for x in df.col.values for z in x])
89.2 µs ± 2.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution worked for me..

Comment: I have a question, this method drops all the nan values, which i don't want to, how can I do that ??

Comment: @id101112 just use `stack(dropna=False)` ;)

Comment: this is not working, this is adding extra Nan columns in the dataframe, issue not resolved yet @RafaelC

Comment: @id101112 what about the second method? `pd.Series([z for x in df.col.values for z in x])` ?

Comment: yes, this method works fine, but the thing is i need those repetitive ids also, which are shown as my required output, and i only get those if I do df.index, i am not sure with loop,. how can I get those repetitive ids here, so the first method was more better to apply

Comment: @RafaeIC thanks, i figured out, and it worked for me.